# Tidy up .html.erb output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

My application layout has a login/logout link that displays depending on whether you are signed in or not:

```
<% if signed_in? %>
    <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, :method => :delete %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %>
<% end %>
```

This works fine, but seems really untidy and verbose. How can I output the appropriate link_to without so many <%...%> brackets?

Comment: Try the HAML gem. It will do you good. :) http://haml-lang.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/) ;)

```
- if signed_in?
  = link_to "Sign out", signout_path, :method => :delete
- else
  = link_to "Sign in", signin_path
```

Comment: Ah! Haml instantly feels like a great fit for me. Thanks guys. *Taps fingers until I can choose as answer*

Comment: And remember! Haml is sweeping the rails world like a wildfire of chicken, and everyone wants the biggest piece.

Comment: @Rich: Time Machine was first. I always get stuck until the answer looks pretty. :)

Comment: Very gracious of you; if Time Machine adds it as an answer I'll select that but in the meantime I'll choose this and give a great comment to his earlier response.

Comment: @Rich: My comment was a suggestion, not an answer. Leave it as is. Heikki needs some reputation as he is new here. :) <— Time Machine is just lazy

Answer (score 5):

I'd go with HAML, but if you don't want to use HAML, you could use a [ternary operator](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/ruby/examples-ruby-ternary-operator-true-false-syntax):

```
<%= signed_in? ? link_to( 'Sign Out', signout_path, :method => :delete ) : link_to( 'Sign In', signin_path ) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the concat helper:  (ActionView::Helpers::TextHelper)

```
<% 
if signed_in? 
   concat link_to( "Sign out", signout_path, :method => :delete )
else
   concat link_to( "Sign in", signin_path )
end
%>
```

Though in the rails api they prefer the <% %> syntax....

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a - (dash) to your closing tag, like so:

```
<% if signed_in? -%>
    <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, :method => :delete -%>
<% else -%>
    <%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path -%>
<% end -%>
```

From: http://www.plexusweb.com/staff/travis/blog/post/117/Rails-inline-ERb-effects-on-HTML-structure

Edit;
My bad, thought is was about formatting the HTML output (newlines etc.)

Answer (score 0):

With 2 open-close brackets you could do it like this:

```
<%= link_to( "Sign out", signout_path, :method => :delete ) if signed_in? %>
<%= link_to( "Sign in", signin_path) if !signed_in? %>
```